# Debugging C++ code with Eclipse, the view Variables is empty and no tooltip showing variable value

Tags: c++, eclipse, gdb, eclipse-cdt

I am writing some C++ code in Eclipse + CDT under Ubuntu 15.10. When I debug, the view "Variables" contains only "std::__ioinit" and no other value appears as variables are created. Furthermore when I stop the mouse over a variable the tooltip doesn't show the variable value, but only the part of code where I declare the variable. Do you know how to actually have it display variables?

I'm using Eclipse 3.8.1, with CDT 8.0.2 and GDB 7.4.

Note: If I launch gdb from the shell it says that gdb version is

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4-2012.02-0ubuntu2) 7.4-2012.02
```

But if I go to Help -> About Eclipse platform -> CDT button I have this information:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Are you debugging a debug build, with `-g` on the compile line?

Comment: And are you stopped at a breakpoint within a scope where the variable is defined?

Comment: Yes, I am in a point where the variable is visible. However I can't see any variable, so it's not for a single variable that it doesn't work. How do I check if I have -g on the compile line? I tried to go to "Debug configurations" -> Name of the project - > Arguments and add "-g" but there is no change

Comment: Under "Project properties -> C/C++ build" Configuration is set to Debug [active]

Comment: Using a build configuration named "Debug" is not the same thing as having the compile option set for debug. Check the project build settings.

Comment: @Marco Please consider upgrading Eclipse and CDT. The version you are using is 4-5 years old, as is GDB.

Comment: @Marco Can you provide a [MCVE] of your problem, i.e. Hello World size with the command line you are using to build? Also you have launched GDB from the shell, is GDB displaying the correct information on its own? i.e. do `gdb program.elf` followed by `b main` then `run` then `info locals`

Comment: This is the version of Eclipse present in Ubuntu's repos and I had to downgrade gdb to be able to actually debug.

Comment: I don't have any elf file...

Comment: OK, I could run it also with `gdb program`. After the commands you said:

`(gdb) info locals
std::__ioinit = {static _S_refcount = <optimised out>, 
 static _S_synced_with_stdio = <optimised out>}`

stepping with the command `s` and running info locals the output remains the same (even though stepping I saw that I declared new variables)

Comment: When you (re)build your project in eclipse, build console shows build log. Can you show us this? It is probable that you are building with optimization enabled. Go to project properties, then C/C++ build, then Settings and see Optimization and Debugging groups (Should be None (-O0) and Maximum (-g3)). If this is makefile based project, you need to modify makefile appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved upgrading the version of Eclipse. Apparently on Ubuntu's repos there is an old version. I downloaded the last version and installed it, like shown here:

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/01/how-to-install-the-latest-eclipse-in-ubuntu-16-04-15-10/

now variables appear.